# How to insert three line breaks for the axis label in ggplot AND add greek symbols?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot a figure with many panels, therefore, I do not have a lot of space on the y-axis and need to insert line breaks.
This can be done easily with /n in ggplot.
However, I have superscripts etc and I need to add also a greek symbol.
I managed to have two line breaks, but adding a third line and a greek symbol is somehow not possible....

```r
library (car)
data(cars)
ggplot(cars, aes(x=dist,y=speed))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x="Sand (%)", y= expression(atop(fully~corrected~basal~respiration,"expression(delta) ("*µl~O[2]~h^{-1}~g^{-1}~dry~soil*")")))
```

In the first line I would like to have "fully corrected".
In the second line "basal respiration".
In the third line the unit and before the greek delta symbol Δ.
Thanks!

Comment: Why is it not possible? Are you getting an error or is the symbol simply gone? What code did you use when it failed? Stackoverflow is for questions about programming problems, not a coding service. It'd make for a better question if you used your code or even better a [Minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As the question is currently phrased, you have tried and encountered a problem. Knowing more specifics about your particular problem will increase your chances of receiving an answer and help others in the future.

Comment: You can nest `atop()` but that is probably not a good idea. Why do you need three lines anyway? The current code would work with `y= expression(atop(fully~corrected~basal~respiration,Delta*µl~O[2]~h^{-1}~g^{-1}~dry~soil))`

Comment: ok, this is helpful! Thanks. I will try to nest it.